# Why does USB Ethernet 2.5GBit device show up under weird name in ifconfig?

Tags: usb, ethernet

When I plug in a USB3 Ethernet device, my Ubuntu 20.10 system picks it up:

```
[323680.309144] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[323680.329754] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8156, bcdDevice=31.00
[323680.329758] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[323680.329760] usb 2-1: Product: USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
[323680.329762] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[323680.329764] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 001000001
```

And it shows up in ifconfig too, but with a really weird name that has its MAC Address postfixed to it.

```
$ ifconfig
...
enxAAAAAAAAAAAA: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

... where AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA stands for its Mac Address.

Whatever happened to eth0: eth1: eth2: and the likes?

It shows up with lsusb as:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
```

The serial nr looks pretty suspect, as well.

Comment: Those are now considered predictable names.  You can disable that by following through the answer here:  https://serverfault.com/questions/741210/disabling-predictable-network-interface-names-in-xubuntu-15-10

Comment: In addition to @Terrance excellent comment, enx refers to, roughly, EtherNt eXternal. A usb wireless woud be wlxAAAA ... for WireLess eXternal, etc. A PCI device is typically enp (for PCI) and a reference to the PCI bus.

Comment: What you call weird we call predictable.  All a matter of opinion :+

Comment: Also, if you decide to go with the non-predictable names look into using `udev` rules on the system so that the MAC address of the device is assigned to the same name after every reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the "old" naming scheme, that used interface names like `eth0`, `eth1` and so forth, the names were assigned in the order the interfaces were encountered during the boot process. As long as the boot process was relatively straightforward, this order would probably not change between reboots. So you could expect that the interface that "showed up" first today (and therefore became `eth0`) would also show up first tomorrow, and therefore be assigned the same name. And the day after tomorrow, and so on.

But over time, the boot process became more involved and less linear. Also, hotpluggable interfaces (that can be added and removed while the machine is running) became more common. As you can imagine, that means that the order in which the kernel encounters the interfaces isn't necessarily as stable anymore. What was `eth0` today actually *could* be `eth1` tomorrow, because the detection and initialization of the interfaces did go a bit different this time.

Because of that, the naming scheme was reworked, actually several times over. For more detailed information about the newer schemes, you can for example refer to the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames).